# How to set animations "LoopTime" to false from script (Unity 2020.1.15f1)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I spent good time trying to find any solution but everything I find seems to be for older versions or something? Basically I want to set an AnimationClip.LoopTime from true to false or vice versa from script.

[small pic of the inspector showing AnimationClip.LoopTime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6U6C2.jpg)

I want this to let the object finish the currently running animation cycle. The GameObjects Animator.ApplyRootMotion=true to let the animation occur at the current objects position.

If I just set the Animator to enabled=false like it's advised in some posts, the animation stops right away of course and that leaves the object off position.

I get the desired info with myAnimator.GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo(0)[0].clip.isLooping but that doesn't let me set it...

Somehow it has to be possible to just set looping=false and avoid having to create additional complicated transitions or something with the Animator?

Any help/hint is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried setting its [`wrapMode`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationClip-wrapMode.html)?

Comment: you could simply add an empty animation with normal state and via script, you can play it with GetComponent<Animator>().Play(name);

Comment: @derHugo Yes, somehow that doesn't do anything. There are quite a few posts around that tried it and failed with wrapMode... Seems that that worked somehow in the past but doesn't anymore?

Comment: @Leoverload Sorry, that doesn't work. The Animator on the GameObject is set to ApplyRootMotion=true because the Animation effect is to be applied at the _current_ GameObject.Transform.Position. If I just start another animation the new one already starts at the "offset" position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an event at the end of animation, which would call function inside a script. The function could disable the `Animator` or stop animation, depending on your need for further enabling.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I was rolling this through my head yesterday evening afk and I came to the same conclusion. If anything depends on the frame the animation is in (in my case being back to original position) use an event and notify the puppeteer script. It's easier wo write, understandable when going back and most of all much cleaner.